# Eclipse - Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, solr

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This dependency is causing Eclipse Juno to give a *red cross mark* over **pom.xml** and gives error at `xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">`

with the message

```
Missing artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6
```

This causes another problem; I can't run any class in the same project. Running any class gives error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ...
```

Other projects in the same Eclipse workspace are working fine. Even running **"mvn compile"** command is successful.

I tried many solutions I could find on StackOverflow but nothing worked till now. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding [tools.jar](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#tools-jar-dependency) in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0_05</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```